# On the invariance of the Kaledin class

Tags: homological-algebra, operads, hochschild-cohomology, a-infinity-algebras

In [Formality of DG algebras (after Kaledin)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.0996.pdf), Lunts introduces an $A_\infty$-Hochschild cohomology class, called the Kaledin class, controlling formality of an $A_\infty$-algebra up to a certain order. For minimal $A_\infty$ algebras with just two multiplications, the binary multiplication $m_2$ and an $n$-ary multiplication $m_n$, this class is simply the Hochschild class of $m_n$ in the Hochschild cohomology $HHoch(A,A)$ of the associative algebra $(A,m_2)$ with coefficients in itself as an $A$-$A$-bimodule. Then invariance of the Kaledin class means that if $(A,m_2,m_n)$ and $(A,m_2,\tilde{m}_n)$ are two $A_\infty$-algebras with the same underlying $(A,m_2)$, these are $A_\infty$-isomorphic up to order $n$ if and only if $[m_n]=[\tilde{m}_n]$ in $HHoch(A,A)$. On direction is clear: if $[m_n]=[\tilde{m}_n]$ then there exists $\phi_{n-1}$ such that $d_{Hoch}\phi_{n-1}=m_n-\tilde{m}_n$, and then $(\mathrm{id}_A,0,0,\dots,\phi_{n-1})$ is an isomorphism of $A_\infty$-algebras up to order $n$. Notice that this is an isomorphism of a very special kind. The inverse direction is elusive to me: clearly if there is an isomorphism of very special kind between $(A,m_2,m_n)$ and $(A,m_2,\tilde{m}_n)$ this precisely gives $d_{Hoch}\phi_{n-1}=m_n-\tilde{m}_n$ and we are done, but I'm presently unable to see that if an isomorphism up to order $n$ of the general form $(\mathrm{id}_A,\psi_2,\psi_3,\dots,\psi_{n-1})$ exists (it is not restrictive to assume that the linear component is the identity), then also an isomorphism of the special form $(\mathrm{id}_A,0,0,\dots,\phi_{n-1})$ exists. Indeed, the existence of $(\mathrm{id}_A,\psi_2,\psi_3,\dots,\psi_{n-1})$ is equivalent to an equation of the form
$$
m_n-\tilde{m}_n=d_{Hoch}\psi_{n-1}+\sum_{i=2}^{n-2} \pm m_2(\psi_i,\psi_{n-i}) 
$$
and it is not clear to me how to get rid of the quadratic terms on the right.

It must be said that in Lunt's paper there is not a completely explicit statement on the invariance of the Kaledin class in the terms I described above, but this is hinted to in the proof of the "clear part" of Proposition 4.5. An explicit statement on the invariance of the Kaledin class can be found in [Formality criteria for algebras over operads](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.09229.pdf), where it is Lemma 2.10. However the proof Melani and Rubió provide reduces to showing that it is not restrictive to assume that the linear part of the isomorphism is the identity, and then they conclude by saying that the result for isomorphisms of the form $(\mathrm{id}_A,\psi_2,\psi_3,\dots,\psi_{n-1})$ "is essentially the content of [[1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.0996.pdf), Lemmas 4.1 and Proposition 7.3]". This I can agree with, but I have to admit I'm unable to see how it should actually work even in the very simple case of algebras with just two multiplications $m_2$ and $m_n$ as in this question. (of course for $n=3$ the statement is trivially true since there is no quadratic part to be considered, but already for $n=4$ I find it elusive).

Comment: For $n>3$ that class would not be invariant unless some extra condition holds, like $A$ being concentrated in degrees $(n-2)\mathbb{Z}$. The class of $m_3$ predates Lunts and Orlov. It was studied by Baues and his collaborators in different papers since the late 1980s, in a more general topological context. They call it universal Toda blackberry and provide references for earlier appearances. In the A-infinity setting there’s a nice paper from 2004 by Benson, Krause and Schwede. For general $n$ you can find a proof of invariance under the previous conditions in https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.14413

Comment: It is proposition 4.4.4 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.14413

Comment: Ah, ok! The $m_3$ case is indeed easy and natural. And I see how can generalize using sparsness of the degrees (thanks a lot for the reference!). But then I am confused: should I deduce that Lemma 2.10 in Melani and Rubió (and so the crucial Proposition 2.9 therein) is inaccurate? Actually for what I'm working on at the moment $m_3$ is all I need, but I'd like to have a clear understanding of the general picture.

Comment: I’m not familiar with those references. I’ll have a look when time permits. Nevertheless I think our invariance result is sharp. Gaps look necessary. BTW I’ve spotted a typo: blackberry = bracket.

Comment: Another typo: Orlov = Kaledin (I had another paper in mind).